# unpivot and pivot in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, unpivot

I need to see the houre_key in row. I used to unpivot but I had an error. For example, I should create the same as the picture :

[image]

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT date_key,
               cell_name,
               hour_key,
               handover_preparation_rate_eucell_eric_,
               TRUNC(sysdate) - TO_DATE(date_key, 'yyyymmdd') AS days
          FROM edw.fct_prse4g_cell_kpi_h
         WHERE province = 'KJ'
           AND date_key BETWEEN TO_CHAR(sysdate - 2, 'yyyymmdd') AND
               TO_CHAR(sysdate - 1, 'yyyymmdd')
           AND hour_key BETWEEN 0 AND 8) 
       UNPIVOT(hour_key FOR hour_key in(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
  PIVOT(
        SUM(handover_preparation_rate_eucell_eric_)
        FOR days IN(2 AS hand_48, 1 AS hand_24)
       ) pvt1
```

Comment: What is your current issue? If the query result doesn't meet your expectations or you have any errors then please update the question and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to `UNPIVOT`, just `PIVOT` with multiple columns in the pivot:

```sql
SELECT  *
FROM    (
  SELECT CELL_NAME,
         HOUR_KEY,
         HANDOVER_PREPARATION_RATE_EUCELL_ERIC_,
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TO_DATE(DATE_KEY, 'YYYYMMDD') AS days
  FROM   EDW.FCT_PRSE4G_CELL_KPI_H 
  WHERE  PROVINCE='KJ'
  AND    DATE_KEY BETWEEN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE -2,'YYYYMMDD')
                      AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE -1,'YYYYMMDD') 
  AND    HOUR_KEY BETWEEN 0 AND 8
) 
PIVOT ( 
  SUM(HANDOVER_PREPARATION_RATE_EUCELL_ERIC_)
  FOR (days, hour_key) IN (
    (2, 0) AS HAND_48_0,
    (2, 1) AS HAND_48_1,
    (2, 2) AS HAND_48_2,
    (2, 3) AS HAND_48_3,
    (2, 4) AS HAND_48_4,
    (2, 5) AS HAND_48_5,
    (2, 6) AS HAND_48_6,
    (2, 7) AS HAND_48_7,
    (2, 8) AS HAND_48_8,
    (1, 0) AS HAND_24_0,
    (1, 1) AS HAND_24_1,
    (1, 2) AS HAND_24_2,
    (1, 3) AS HAND_24_3,
    (1, 4) AS HAND_24_4,
    (1, 5) AS HAND_24_5,
    (1, 6) AS HAND_24_6,
    (1, 7) AS HAND_24_7,
    (1, 8) AS HAND_24_8
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EDW.FCT_PRSE4G_CELL_KPI_H (date_key, cell_name, hour_key, HANDOVER_PREPARATION_RATE_EUCELL_ERIC_, province) AS
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 0, 1, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 0, 2, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 0, 3, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 1, 1, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 1, 4, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 2, 1, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 3, 3, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-2, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 0, 2, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-2, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 0, 3, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-2, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 0, 4, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-2, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 1, 2, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-2, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 1, 5, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-2, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 2, 2, 'KJ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-2, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'AAA', 3, 4, 'KJ' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CELL_NAME | HAND_48_0 | HAND_48_1 | HAND_48_2 | HAND_48_3 | HAND_48_4 | HAND_48_5 | HAND_48_6 | HAND_48_7 | HAND_48_8 | HAND_24_0 | HAND_24_1 | HAND_24_2 | HAND_24_3 | HAND_24_4 | HAND_24_5 | HAND_24_6 | HAND_24_7 | HAND_24_8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 9 | 7 | 2 | 4 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 6 | 5 | 1 | 3 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

*Note: If you want `0` instead of `NULL` when there are missing values then name the columns and wrap them with `COALESCE`. For example, `COALESCE(hand_48_0, 0) AS hand_48_0`.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jsdhrvYm)